How to implement waiting for transaction validaton?
I'm running a bot that is making a series of smart contract calls on Avalanche c-chain from one account. I'm checking for transaction validation by waiting for a nonce increase with
export async function waitFinalize(
    provider: JsonRpcProvider,
    signer: Signer,
    prms: Promise<ContractTransactionResponse>
): Promise<ContractTransactionReceipt> {
    const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(signer)
    let response = await prms
    while ((await provider.getTransactionCount(signer)) === nonce) {
        await sleep(500)
    }
    await sleep(1_000)
    return response as any
}

But in some rare cases this still produces nonce too low: address 0x08C4816E183e260eDffaD93B332290Cb74A04e37 current nonce (9) > tx nonce (8). Note that my rpc is fixed. How can I make this more robust, so that when I send txB I can be sure that txA was finalized and nonce had been increased?
